# How reliable is (or will be) btrfs send/receive?

Tags: backup, btrfs

We have at work a 15TB NFS file server using XFS, with a distant clone for backups using `rsync`, over a moderately slow connection (100Mb ethernet).

We are now thinking about using btrfs instead of XFS and use send/receive to synchronize the data more efficiently.

However fs corruption is probably unavoidable (we already experienced a 4-days fs repair operation with our XFS system), so the question is:

Will a future corruption be transferred and happily applied to the remote machine, if we use send/receive?

Comment: I guess it depends on the kind of corruption. By design send & receive transmit only valid btrfs transactions, but if there are bugs in the btrfs code itself then everything is possible.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using btrfs send for backups, and found it to be workable, though with frequent failures.  It's important to detect a failed send and delete any partial/corrupt received volumes.  I have not had any corruption problems after a successful send.  I've written a "sync" utility for btrfs snapshots that detects failures, and also includes a checksumdir script for verifying correctness: https://github.com/AmesCornish/buttersink  If you look at it, I'd love to know whether you find it useful or not.